# Select menu option's text by double click on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have menu list with recent 10 contacts with name and number without navigation link (ie.  anchor `<a href="javascript:void(0);"></a>` tag)

I want to select name or number by double clicking on it without closing menu options list. Is this possible?

I used `stopPropagation()` method to preventing closing menu option. How can I achieve selecting text by double click?

Comment: Share your html and js code. Show us what you tried!

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/dblclick

Comment: @Takit Isy it is simple dropdown menu list

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to accomplish exactly since you didn't provide any code. But from what you are asking I think is what you want to use.

```
document.getElementById("YourMenuID").getElementsByTagName("a").ondblclick = function(){
//request you value here
};
```

Comment: I just want to select particular text by double clicking on it not a complete sentence

Comment: so just use above function on the particular text you want? or provide your specific code as asked above so we have some more information to work with.